# Azure Bicep - unable to set ipSecurityRestrictions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have the following resource defined in a bicep module for the setting of function app config:

```
resource functionAppAppsettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2018-11-01' = {
  name: '${functionAppName}/appsettings'
  properties: {
    AzureWebJobsStorage: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccountId, '2019-06-01').keys[0].value}'
    WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccountId, '2019-06-01').keys[0].value}'
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION: '~3'
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: 'dotnet'
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY: appInsightsKey
    WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE: toLower(functionAppName)
    ipSecurityRestrictions: [
      {
        ipAddress: '${pcPublicIp}/32'
        action: 'Allow'
        tag: 'Default'
        priority: 101
        name: 'laptop ip'
        description: 'Allow requests from test laptop'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I comment out the *ipSecurityRestrictions* block then it works ok but with it in, I get the following error:

```
"Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value."
    },
    {
      "Code": "BadRequest"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "ExtendedCode": "51008",
        "MessageTemplate": "The parameter {0} has an invalid value.",
        "Parameters": [
          "properties"
        ],
        "Code": "BadRequest",
        "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value."
      }
    }
```

The pcPublicIp variable is a string containing a ip v4 address.

Can you anyone see what I have wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a `web` config section to configure `ipSecurityRestrictions` (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-web?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)):

```bicep
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2018-11-01' existing = {
  name: functionAppName
}

// Web
resource webConfig 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2018-11-01' = {
  parent: functionApp
  name: 'web'
  properties: {
    ipSecurityRestrictions: [
      {
        ipAddress: '${pcPublicIp}/32'
        action: 'Allow'
        tag: 'Default'
        priority: 101
        name: 'laptop ip'
        description: 'Allow requests from test laptop'
      }
    ]
  }
}

// AppSettings
resource appSettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2018-11-01' = {
  parent: functionApp
  name: 'appsettings'
  properties: {
    AzureWebJobsStorage: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccountId, '2019-06-01').keys[0].value}'
    WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccountId, '2019-06-01').keys[0].value}'
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION: '~3'
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: 'dotnet'
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY: appInsightsKey
    WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE: toLower(functionApp.name)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Thomas another nice answer and lesson learned. I had been using multi segment resource names to identify parent but better to obtain a ref to the parent using "existing" keyword, then use this in "parent" property of child resource

Comment: The parent is more verbose if you need to reference an `existing` resource but I saw on github that there is a plan to deprecate the multi segment in favor of parent.